# javax.xml.bind.JAXBException while generating word document from XHTML in cq5

Tags: aem, docx4j

I am trying to convert HTML> XHTML to word document, using docx4j library. While hitting the servlet I get this exception.

I have converted docx4j jar to OSGi bundle and in my classpath 1.7.0_21 is set.

java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: JAXB: neither Reference Implementation nor Java 6 implementation present?
    at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.marshaltoString(XmlUtils.java:546)
    at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.marshaltoString(XmlUtils.java:478)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.StyleDefinitionsPart.createVirtualStylesForDocDefaults(StyleDefinitionsPart.java:330)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.MainDocumentPart.getStyleTree(MainDocumentPart.java:172)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.MainDocumentPart.getStyleTree(MainDocumentPart.java:161)
    at org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.XHTMLImporterImpl.stylesToCSS(XHTMLImporterImpl.java:424)
    at org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.XHTMLImporterImpl.getRenderer(XHTMLImporterImpl.java:218)
    at org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.XHTMLImporterImpl.convert(XHTMLImporterImpl.java:620)

Comment: What does the following command report: java -version

Answer (score 1):

It reports JRE 1.7 only:

java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)

This issue is now resolved, we had to deploy two more bundles( org.apache.servicemix.bundles.ant-1.7.0 and JAXB).

This might help others !
Thanks

Comment: Adding the JAXB bundle makes sense; not sure what the other would add?

Comment: JAXB bundle has a dependency on ant-1.7.0. To resolve this we added rg.apache.servicemix.bundles.ant-1.7.0

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same issue regarding the exception, and what helped me was to introduce following into my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.jaxb-namespaceprefixmapper-interfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>JAXBNamespacePrefixMapper</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Tried a few different solutions before this one, but this was the one that made the magic happen for me.